# Dataframe from several series

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I am trying to create a dataframe from two series. And the code below works in JupyterLab, but does not in Jupyter Notebook with error  'dict' object is not callable'
What am I doing wrong?

```
import pandas as pd
my_series1 = pd.Series([1, 2, 3], index = ["Loid", "Clara", "MArj"])
my_series2 = pd.Series([4, 5, 6], index = ["Loid", "Clara", "MArj"])
pd.DataFrame({"name": my_series1, "name2": my_series2})
```

Expecting a new DataFrame to be created from two series.

Comment: Same, it works fine for me. What version of python are you running this on? Mine is `3.8.2` and jupyter is `6.4.3`.

Comment: @Andrey, in the future for a place enabling an independent test you can use a temporary, remote Jupyter session in your broswer without need for logging in. (The one I'm pointing at here also already has Pandas so no installs needed.) Importantly, a MyBinder-served session allows you to try both JupyterLab and the classic Jupyter notebook. Go [here](https://github.com/binder-examples/requirements#python-environment-with-a-requirementstxt) and click 'launch binder'. The session will spin up in JupyterLab. You can switch by going to 'Help' > 'Launch Classic Notebook'.

Comment: That suggestion will have the same Python and Pandas version in both Jupyter options. Eliminating that as a possible confounding issue. Marcelo is on the right path, I think. I would suspect you may be running your Jupyters each in a different environment and perhaps not realizing? Maybe the Pandas version is different between the two?

Comment: People, thank you all for your responces. Not gonna write a line of code for a week as I am not worthy with so stupid question.